# Logging Python keywords to log.html like robot keywords

Tags: robotframework

I would like to ask If there is a possibility to log python keywords to log.html like robot keywords. If we executin Robot/Python keyword from robot file it's ok - there is a "node" for keyword. When we run python keyword and if that keyword contain other keywords inside, these keywords are not logged properly - doesn't have own node. In log.html that keywords are under one "node" (parent), executed from robot file.
Is there any decorator for keywords or other method to "tell" for robot that methods inside that keyword are too keywords?

Robot:

- Run Something

  +Run other keyword

  +Execute command

Python:

- Run something

....

....

Thank you in advance for your help.
Br, Tomasz

Comment: To me it's not clear what you mean with Python and Robot. Can you elaborate on the difference?

Comment: Python - keyword from python library used in robot test
Robot - keyword from robot resource used in robot test

If u start Robot keyword which contains other keywords - these keyword will log properly in log.html as a tree, but when u use python keyword in robot test and that keyword contains other keywords from python library, then these keywords inside won't log properly as a tree. Only main keyword executed from robot test will show and internal keywords will be under main node.

Comment: I prepared an example, difference between robot keywords and python keywords:
http://imageshack.com/a/img923/3444/FICBkW.png
http://imageshack.com/a/img924/8213/VyyPao.png

In case of python keywords, only Show My Name keyword has node in log.html

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Python "keywords" are not keywords.

Answer (score 0):

Your image in comments helped me to realize your problem.

> Is there any decorator for keywords or other method to "tell" for robot that methods inside that keyword are too keywords?

As I know, there isn't such decorator. Robot has no knowledge about internal call-graph of a Python keyword and is unable to produce tree-like structure for logs of your internal function calls.

I think, there is a workaround for that. Logging and return value are the only ways that you can communicate to Robot Framework from within your Python code and tell it something. I suggest you to use logging API to make your Robot Framework log more structured and this decorator is one of several things you can do:

```
from robot.api import logger

def logged_keyword(some_function):
    def wrapper():
        logger.info('start of {}'.format(some_function.__name__))
        some_function()
        logger.info('end of {}'.format(some_function.__name__))
    return wrapper

def show_my_name():
    logger.info('Tommy')
    print_colour()

@logged_keyword
def print_colour():
    logger.info('blue')
    print_other_colour()

@logged_keyword
def print_other_colour():
    logger.info('white')
```

There is a way to tell to Robot Framework that you are logging HTML rather than plain text; so, you can use a decorator to log HTML mark-ups to help Robot Framework structure your log messages. Maybe the HTML source of Robot Framework log is a good place to start (inspect element in browser).

```
def markuped_keyword(some_function):
    def wrapper():
        logger.info('<div>', html=True)
        some_function()
        logger.info('</div>', html=True)
    return wrapper
```

You should refine the mark-up to have a tree-like structure for your logs.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I used it already. Now I have table with method name, library name, parameters, but i thought that i will find better solution.

Comment: Excellent! Please share your solution with us if possible. Maybe it's helpful for someone.